# add multiple google font on style tag in svg

Tags: css, svg, fonts, google-font-api

I made svg contains some text and i want to use Google font as font-family on that text. There are multiple text and i want to use multiple Google font URL in style sheet.

I try my way but it's not working. my style sheet

```
<style type="text/css"> 
      @font-face {
          font-family: 'Freckle Face';
          src: url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Freckle Face') format('svg')
      }
</style>
```

I try  a lot but not success. please help me and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Sorry friends for disturb you. I found solution of it.

Style sheet

```
<style xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" type="text/css">
  @import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Audiowide');
  @import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto'); 
</style>
```

just importing URL

Comment: Actually you could just go with `@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Audiowide|Roboto);`